# Bash autocomplete behaviour in Debian 8

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bashrc, debian-jessie, bash-alias

On a new install of Debian 8 (Jessie) I have found that the autocompletion in bash, using the `tab` key, has changed.

The test I did was:

1. Open a terminal (in my case `Konsole`).
   Above the prompt it shows
   `~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
2. `mkdir -p /tmp/test` # create test directory
3. `cd /tmp/test` # go into the empty directory
4. `ls <tab> <tab> <tab> <tab>`
   `/tmp/test /tmp/test ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` # after 1 `tab`
   `/tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` # after 2 `tab`s
   `/tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` # after 3 `tab`s
   `/tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` # after 4 `tab`s

It used to just show the files in the directory (if any).
Does anyone know what causes this? Something in `.bashrc`? Happy to send more files if that helps!

Comment: Obvious question, but do you have the `bash-completion` package? Let's have the output of `dpkg -l | grep bash`.

Comment: `ii  bash  4.3-11+b1  amd64  GNU Bourne Again SHell` and `ii  bash-completion 1:2.1-4  all  programmable completion for the bash shell`

Comment: Weird. Running Jessie here, and it produces the list of files as expected.

Comment: it's also odd that for programs in the path it works as expected. So 'pdf'`tab` (2x) gives a list of 40 or so pdf tools, and 'pdfl'`tab` gives 'pdflatex'. It must be something in .bashrc or .profile gone wrong, I just cannot find what.

Comment: Check your local `.bashrc` and also `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` to see if there is anything screwy in any of those. I don't have a `.profile`. I don't think that is standard, at least in Debian. It might also be worth looking at the output of `set` to see if there is anything in there, though that's usually a lot of stuff.

Comment: Ha! I found that in my old `.bash_aliases` file it said `alias [='pushd .'` and `alias ]='popd'` which I did use a fair bit in the olden days. Commenting those out in the current copy solved the immediate problem, although it's still intriguing what made these aliases stop working between Debian 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this riddle in 2 steps. Firstly, my old `.bash_aliases` used `alias [='pushd .'` and `alias ]='popd'`. Removing those lines solved the strange behaviour above but I had lost my aliases.

But if I keep those aliases in and put the line

```
if [[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]]; then
   . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

in `.bashrc` *after* the line

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
   if [[ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]]; then
      . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   elif [[ -f /etc/bash_completion ]]; then
      . /etc/bash_completion
   fi
fi
```

then I can both keep my `[` and `]` aliases *and* have normal autocompletion. So it appears the aliases interfered with Jessie's autocompletion set-up in Bash. The only reason that the call of `.bash_aliases` was before the call of the autocompletion scripts originally, was that in the template `.bashrc` supplied with the installation they were in that order.

Comment: only possible 24h later :)